# auth url doesn't work in yahoo

Tags: authentication, yahoo

I am doing login with yahoo from my site.

I used the code given from https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php

snippet of sample code:

```
$hasSession = YahooSession::hasSession(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUTH_APP_ID);
if($hasSession == FALSE) {
  // create the callback url,
  $callback = YahooUtil::current_url()."?in_popup";
    $sessionStore = new NativeSessionStore();

  $auth_url = YahooSession::createAuthorizationUrl(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, $callback, $sessionStore);

}
```

here the $auth_url gives empty value. its return null. Also I given correct consumer-key, secret-key and app-id.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace your current Yahoo Api library with the below github branch.

```
https://github.com/syamvilakudy/yos-social-php
```